# How do I scp from inside a Linux container to Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker, scp

I am able to `scp` a directory from within a Linux (alpine:3) docker container to my windows 10 box (a VM). The problem is that after the copy successfully completes, it prints this error:

```
sshpass -p $MY_PASSWORD scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r -q /tmp/work chip@10.1.2.4:/C:/Users/cdebergh.DOMAIN/source/repos/work
Program 'scp.exe' failed to run: Win32 internal error "Access is denied" 0x5 occurred while reading the console output 
buffer. Contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.At line:1 char:1
+ scp.exe -r -t /C:/Users/cdebergh.DOMAIN/source/repos/work
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ scp.exe -r -t /C:/Users/cdebergh.DOMAIN/source/repos/work
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

And then exits the container with an exit code of 1. I had this issue with remote `ssh` commands and fixed it by forcing pseudo tty with the `-tt` argument. However, this does not exist for `scp` as far as I can tell from the docs. How can I accomplish this or at least suppress the error so that the container completes successfully?

*Note*: I am using `sshpass` instead of host keys because my password is securely stored in my macOS keychain. Where I then pass it to the ephemeral container as an environment variable, for `sshpass`, during execution. The container self-destroys after execution completes along with the password. I'd rather not have a sensitive file to manage (host private key) to keep this contained and temporary during execution.